# iframe. Display another html page in it; whats the simplest implementation?

Tags: html, iframe

Heres what I tried...

In Main html page....

```
 <iframe src="./example.html" id="frame" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```

and example.html looks like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>YOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</p>
</body>
```

This results in empty iframe.

--UPDATE--

Ok,the problem was that simply refreshing the page did not update the iframe. but when I clsed it and reopened it it was fine. Can someone explain this? Do iframes need to be refreshed?

Comment: Are you getting a empty iFrame? Any error in the console?

Comment: Are you sure you got the src correctly?

Comment: Add `</html>` in the end of example.html, in case you don't have it...

Comment: @Sergio Yes empty iframe.. added </html>, that was missing but no change cheers. Mataniko  Yes I think src is right.. its a file called example.html in same folder as main html file with iframe in it

Comment: If you look at the source code of main html and follow the link of the iFrame src (click in the link in the view-source) what happens?

Comment: @Sergio... eh, in what browser are talking about?

Comment: view source code / view page code / view page source - any browser. Which do you use?

Comment: Yes, iFrames don't always refresh when you refresh the page. Was it the </html> that was missing?

Comment: yeah, but that actually didnt affect things at all! html is quite forgiving of errors it seems  :)  Anyway I am sorted now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example.html should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>YOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also make sure your path to example.html is correct in your iframe, as well as having a set height & width.